# GitBash switch to the newly created directory just after the repository has been cloned

Tags: git, directory, git-bash, cd, last-modified

I have GitBash 2.27.0 installed in Windows 10 64Bit OS. And I have repository to be cloned through URL.

Now I want to automatically enter into the newly created directory right after the cloning is complete. In Windows when you have new directory created in C: drive(I have to use C drive, as all my projects are in it), the directory that's last modified is `C:\System Volume Information`.

So I think this code directly doesn't help, and I have very less experience in Bash coding involving directory modified time:

```
cd "$(\ls -1dt ./*/ | head -n 1)"
```

So how do I ignore that change and enter into the directory only created by git cloning in GitBash ?

Comment: Are you cloning into the currently directory or some path. ie `git clone myrepo.git` or `git clone myrepo.git /My/New/Path/myrepo`

Comment: Current directory, and I know that we can specify the folder of cloning, but I would like to get the folder name automatically rather than actually typing it, as generalized version command or script..

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper function (`cdclone`) which :

- takes an url as argument
- extracts the last fragment of the url in a variable
- calls `git clone $url`
- cd to the extracted fragment

If you want to `cd` you need a *function*, so that you can change the working directory *of your current shell*.

An alternative would be to write a script, which calls `echo $fragment` as its last action, and an additional one liner to get that value and cd to it

Comment: You can also extract the target directory from the regular output of `git clone`